# Guardar imagen en MySQL y leerla en Android

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

Bueno, tengo el siguiente problema:

- Tengo una aplicación web con la cual quiero poder guardar registros de 2 tablas, las cuales deben contener imágenes. Quiero guardar esos registros (con todo e imágenes) en un servidor MySQL para que después pueda leer esos registros y mostrar sus imágenes en una aplicación Android.

El problema es que debo poder consultar los registros aun cuando el dispositivo Android que esté usando no tenga conexión a Internet, es decir, debo clonar la base de datos de MySQL en una base de datos SQLite cada que el dispositivo sea conectado a internet.

Ahora, según entiendo lo primero que debo hacer es crear el servidor MySQL, después conectarlo a la app web y guardar los registros ahí, mi primera pregunta es: **¿Qué tipo de dato debo usar para guardar las imágenes? De modo que una vez que clone la base de datos de MySQL a SQLite pueda leer las imagenes en la app Android?**

Mi segunda pregunta, no tengo la más mínima idea de como clonar una base de datos MySQL  a SQLite, **¿Me podrían proporcionar un ejemplo?**

Mi tercera pregunta, (que debió haber sido la primera): Entre las 2 tablas voy a tener un promedio de 100 a 150 registros, es decir 150 imágenes (aproximadamente de 960x640)**¿SQLite puede soportar guardar ese número de imágenes?**

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Hola Eduardo, bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español. Permíteme invitarte a visitar [esta presentación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas como funciona la comunidad. Te adelanto que tres preguntas en una sola publicación es demasiado para el formato del sitio, por lo que será puesta en espera hasta que la edites siguiendo [esta guía](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

El tipo de datos para guardar las imágenes en tu servidor es del tipo BLOB, pero acá tienes varios  problemas:

- La base de datos crece mucho en tamaño
- No es posible crear un servicio/API en JSON para intercambiar información  ya que no hay soporte para binarios, solo string.

Lo que normalmente se hace es que en tu base de datos del servidor guardes  el link que apunte a tu imagen, y quedaría como simple texto del tipo VARCHAR (dependiendo de tu base de datos) y funcionaria  impecable con una API en JSON para intercambiar información con tus dispositivos Android.  Ahora,  si obligatoriamente  por una regla de negocio tu quieres guardar la imagen en la BD  y no puedes usar link de referencia de tus imágenes,  solo te quedaría transformar  tus imagen a base64 para que quede como String pero con el costo que tu imagen tendría mala calidad y el intercambio de información seria muy lento.

Para "clonar" tu base de datos tienes dos opciones: hacer una conexión directa con el servidor lo cual es muy mala idea (nadie lo hace) ya que debes tener los accesos de user/pass dentro la aplicación Android y es muy peligroso, y la segunda opción  es por medio de intercambio de datos a través de  un servicio que debes construir en el lado del servidor (API/JSON)  para ser consumido por tus dispositivos.